# How to insert data into hive table from arrays returned by XPath

Tags: xml, powershell, hadoop, xpath, hive

I have a hive query which returns a set of arrays from a XML by using **XPath**. **I want to insert those elements of the array into a hive table.**

The xml content in hivexml table is:

```
<tag><row Id="1" TagName=".net" Count="244006" ExcerptPostId="3624959" WikiPostId="3607476" /><row Id="2" TagName="html" Count="602809" ExcerptPostId="3673183" WikiPostId="3673182" /><row Id="3" TagName="javascript" Count="1274350" ExcerptPostId="3624960" WikiPostId="3607052" /><row Id="4" TagName="css" Count="434937" ExcerptPostId="3644670" WikiPostId="3644669" /><row Id="5" TagName="php" Count="1009113" ExcerptPostId="3624936" WikiPostId="3607050" /><row Id="8" TagName="c" Count="236386" ExcerptPostId="3624961" WikiPostId="3607013" /></tag>
```

The query which returns the set of arrays is:

```
select xpath(str,'/tag/row/@Id'), xpath(str,'/tag/row/@TagName'), xpath(str,'/tag/row/@Count'), xpath(str,'/tag/row/@ExcerptPostId'), xpath(str,'/tag/row/@WikiPostId') from hivexml;"
```

And the output of the above query (the set of arrays) is:

```
["1","2","3","4","5"] [".net","html","css","php","c"]   ["244006","602809","434937","1009113","236386"] ["3624959","3673183","3644670","3624936","3624961"] ["3607476","36
73182","3644669","3607050","3607013"]
```

I want to insert these values into a hive table like in this format:

```
1    .net    244006     3624959    3607476
2    html    602809     3673183    3673182
3    css     434937     3644670    3644669
4    php     1009113    3624936    3607050
5    c       236386     3624961    3607013
```

If I do an insert on the above select query:

```
insert into newhivexml select xpath(str,'/tags/row/@Id'), xpath(str,'/tag/row/@TagName'), xpath(str,'/tag/row/@Count'), xpath(str,'/tag/row/@ExcerptPostId'), xpath(str,'/tag/row/@WikiPostId') from hivexml;"
```

then I am getting an error:

> NoMatchingMethodException No matching method for class
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFToInteger with (array).
>   Possible choices: *FUNC*(bigint)  *FUNC*(boolean)  *FU
>   NC*(decimal(38,18))  *FUNC*(double)  *FUNC*(float)  *FUNC*(smallint) 
>   *FUNC*(string)  *FUNC*(struct)  *FUNC*(timestamp)  *FUNC*(tinyin t)  *FUNC*(void)

I think we cannot insert directly like this, there is something I am missing here. Can anyone tell me how to do this? That is, insert these values from arrays into a table.

Comment: Just to make sure - the XML is just one column in the row, not the entire data, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**xpath_... (str,concat('/tag/row[',pe.pos+1,']/@...))**

```
create table hivexml (str string);

insert into hivexml values ('<tag><row Id="1" TagName=".net" Count="244006" ExcerptPostId="3624959" WikiPostId="3607476" /><row Id="2" TagName="html" Count="602809" ExcerptPostId="3673183" WikiPostId="3673182" /><row Id="3" TagName="javascript" Count="1274350" ExcerptPostId="3624960" WikiPostId="3607052" /><row Id="4" TagName="css" Count="434937" ExcerptPostId="3644670" WikiPostId="3644669" /><row Id="5" TagName="php" Count="1009113" ExcerptPostId="3624936" WikiPostId="3607050" /><row Id="8" TagName="c" Count="236386" ExcerptPostId="3624961" WikiPostId="3607013" /></tag>');
```

---

```
select  xpath_int    (str,concat('/tag/row[',pe.pos+1,']/@Id'           )) as Id  
       ,xpath_string (str,concat('/tag/row[',pe.pos+1,']/@TagName'      )) as TagName
       ,xpath_int    (str,concat('/tag/row[',pe.pos+1,']/@Count'        )) as Count
       ,xpath_int    (str,concat('/tag/row[',pe.pos+1,']/@ExcerptPostId')) as ExcerptPostId
       ,xpath_int    (str,concat('/tag/row[',pe.pos+1,']/@WikiPostId'   )) as WikiPostId

from    hivexml
        lateral view  posexplode (xpath(str,'/tag/row/@Id')) pe
;
```

---

```
+----+------------+---------+---------------+------------+
| id |  tagname   |  count  | excerptpostid | wikipostid |
+----+------------+---------+---------------+------------+
|  1 | .net       |  244006 |       3624959 |    3607476 |
|  2 | html       |  602809 |       3673183 |    3673182 |
|  3 | javascript | 1274350 |       3624960 |    3607052 |
|  4 | css        |  434937 |       3644670 |    3644669 |
|  5 | php        | 1009113 |       3624936 |    3607050 |
|  8 | c          |  236386 |       3624961 |    3607013 |
+----+------------+---------+---------------+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! But one glitch is we cannot put newline in queries..it is showing error "The syntax of the command is incorrect.". If I put everything in one line it is working!

Answer (score 1):

**xpath (str,concat('/tag/row[',pe.pos+1,']/@*'))**

This is a quite clean way to extract all the values of an element together.
What surprised me here it that the order of the attributes does not seem to be according to their order within the XML but in alphabetical order by their names -
@Count,@ExcerptPostId,@Id,@TagName,@WikiPostId

**Unfortunately, I can't consider it as a legitimate solution unless I know that the alphabetical attributes order is guaranteed.**

```
select  xpath (str,concat('/tag/row[',pe.pos+1,']/@*')) as row_values

from    hivexml
        lateral view  posexplode (xpath(str,'/tag/row/@Id')) pe
;
```

--

```
["244006","3624959","1",".net","3607476"]
["602809","3673183","2","html","3673182"]
["1274350","3624960","3","javascript","3607052"]
["434937","3644670","4","css","3644669"]
["1009113","3624936","5","php","3607050"]
["236386","3624961","8","c","3607013"]
```

---

```
select  row_values[2] as Id
       ,row_values[3] as TagName
       ,row_values[0] as Count    
       ,row_values[1] as ExcerptPostId
       ,row_values[4] as WikiPostId

from   (select  xpath (str,concat('/tag/row[',pe.pos+1,']/@*')) as row_values

        from    hivexml
                lateral view  posexplode (xpath(str,'/tag/row/@Id')) pe
        ) x
;
```

---

```
+----+------------+---------+---------------+------------+
| id |  tagname   |  count  | excerptpostid | wikipostid |
+----+------------+---------+---------------+------------+
|  1 | .net       |  244006 |       3624959 |    3607476 |
|  2 | html       |  602809 |       3673183 |    3673182 |
|  3 | javascript | 1274350 |       3624960 |    3607052 |
|  4 | css        |  434937 |       3644670 |    3644669 |
|  5 | php        | 1009113 |       3624936 |    3607050 |
|  8 | c          |  236386 |       3624961 |    3607013 |
+----+------------+---------+---------------+------------+
```

Comment: You are true Hive guru. Didn't even imagine that such things can be done through Hive within a single query. +1 for every solution

Answer (score 1):

**split + str_to_map**

```
select  vals["Id"]              as Id
       ,vals["TagName"]         as TagName
       ,vals["Count"]           as Count    
       ,vals["ExcerptPostId"]   as ExcerptPostId
       ,vals["WikiPostId"]      as WikiPostId

from   (select  str_to_map(e.val,' ','=') as vals

        from    hivexml 
                lateral view  posexplode(split(translate(str,'"',''),'/?><row')) e

        where   e.pos <> 0
        ) x
;
```

---

```
+----+------------+---------+---------------+------------+
| id |  tagname   |  count  | excerptpostid | wikipostid |
+----+------------+---------+---------------+------------+
|  1 | .net       |  244006 |       3624959 |    3607476 |
|  2 | html       |  602809 |       3673183 |    3673182 |
|  3 | javascript | 1274350 |       3624960 |    3607052 |
|  4 | css        |  434937 |       3644670 |    3644669 |
|  5 | php        | 1009113 |       3624936 |    3607050 |
|  8 | c          |  236386 |       3624961 |    3607013 |
+----+------------+---------+---------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

**In case the data is an XML document**

XML serde can be downloaded from https://github.com/01org/graphbuilder/blob/master/src/com/intel/hadoop/graphbuilder/preprocess/inputformat/XMLInputFormat.java

```
add jar /home/cloudera/hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar;

create external table hivexml_ext
(
    Id              string
   ,TagName         string
   ,Count           string
   ,ExcerptPostId   string
   ,WikiPostId      string
)
row format serde 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
with serdeproperties 
(
    "column.xpath.Id"            = "/row/@Id"
   ,"column.xpath.TagName"       = "/row/@TagName"
   ,"column.xpath.Count"         = "/row/@Count    "
   ,"column.xpath.ExcerptPostId" = "/row/@ExcerptPostId"
   ,"column.xpath.WikiPostId"    = "/row/@WikiPostId"
)
stored as
inputformat     'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
outputformat    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
location        '/user/hive/warehouse/hivexml'
tblproperties 
(
    "xmlinput.start" = "<row"
   ,"xmlinput.end"   = "/>"
)
;

select * from hivexml_ext as x
;
```

---

```
+------+------------+---------+-----------------+--------------+
| x.id | x.tagname  | x.count | x.excerptpostid | x.wikipostid |
+------+------------+---------+-----------------+--------------+
|    1 | .net       |  244006 |         3624959 |      3607476 |
|    2 | html       |  602809 |         3673183 |      3673182 |
|    3 | javascript | 1274350 |         3624960 |      3607052 |
|    4 | css        |  434937 |         3644670 |      3644669 |
|    5 | php        | 1009113 |         3624936 |      3607050 |
|    8 | c          |  236386 |         3624961 |      3607013 |
+------+------------+---------+-----------------+--------------+
```

Comment: I dont have java in my pc..will the above code run in powershell if I copy it as it is? I am worried about top line of adding the jar file.

Comment: The `add jar` command should be executed in hive after you have downloaded the jar. Put the jar anywhere you like and change the path accordingly.

Comment: The jar file should be in my local machine or in azure? I've put that in my local machine but its showing -file does not exist.

Comment: I'm less into this stuff. Try to google or open a new SO post.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that XPath function will return you all matching results per each request in independent arrays without joining them. If it suit you, you can use Pig for this as batch model can simplify the process into individual steps:

```
REGISTER /usr/hdp/current/pig-client/lib/piggybank.jar DEFINE XPathAll org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPathAll();

A = LOAD '/tmp/text.xml' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('tag') as (x:chararray);

B = FOREACH A GENERATE XPathAll(x, 'row/@Id',false,false).$0,
    XPathAll(x, 'row/@TagName',false,false).$0,
    XPathAll(x, 'row/@Count',false,false).$0,
    XPathAll(x, 'row/@ExcerptPostId',false,false).$0,
    XPathAll(x, 'row/@WikiPostId',false,false).$0;

DUMP B;

(1,.net,244006,3624959,3607476)
(2,html,602809,3673183,3673182)
(3,javascript,1274350,3624960,3607052)
(4,css,434937,3644670,3644669)
(5,php,1009113,3624936,3607050)
(8,c,236386,3624961,3607013)

STORE B INTO "YourTable" USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer();
```